# Capture value from infinite thread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have created a thread that is running parrallel with main thread. Both threads are doing something infinitely (both have while(true) statement). Main thread while(true) is creating game logic in frames, and second thread is receiveing messages from socket.

Is it possible to get string value of message received from second thread into main thread each frame without returning from second thread?
In c#, I would do it with method invoker but I didn't find anything helpful for c++. Is it possible to perform in c++?

Function which creates thread:

```
void ReceiveMessage() {
    //std::promise<int> p;
    //auto f = p.get_future();
    char buf[1024];
    string usernput;
    int bytesReceived = 0;
    std::thread receiveMessage(&FactoredThread::ThreadFunction, *this);
    receiveMessage.detach();
    //pokusajporuke = f.get();
}
```

ThreadFunction:

```
void ThreadFunction() {
    bytesReceived = 0;
    while (true) {
        bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);
        if (bytesReceived > 0) {
            string primljeniString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++) {
                if (buf[i] != 0)
                {
                    primljeniString += buf[i];
                }
            }
            ZeroMemory(buf, 1024);
            pokusajporuke = primljeniString;

        }
    }
}
```

So how to get "pokusajporuke" string for main thread?

Comment: There are many, many, ways to accomplish this, each with their own advantages and drawbacks. What have you tried up to now? How did it fail?

Comment: please check my pastebin link for code.
https://pastebin.com/dvKXHDJf
So In method ReceiveMessage I am creating another thread function "ThreadFunction". And in threadfunction I want to get "pokusajporuke" to main thread.

Comment: It should be good if you show us some code. I mean, learn [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions and make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. There are many ways of solving this problem.
One way is to use signals and slots, like in Qt. For pure C++ you could use Boost.Signals2, which is thread safe. 
Or you can realize pattern producer-consumer. One thread(producer) puts values into buffer(it should be thread-safe buffer), second takes them from there. 
I think, for your problem second way is better.

Answer (score -1):

Actually what I needed was global static variable. And then with another method from main thread I put that global variable into class property

Comment: This sounds like a terrible way to do it.

Comment: Don't fix whats not broken :D

Comment: Stack Overflow is full of "unbroken" things like this.